# How can I get a random item from multiple arrays based on a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, input

I want to only show the text from the arrays that are selected with the checkboxes (so, if i only want **txt** and **ran**, it only shows options from those arrays)

```js
function myFunc() {
  let txt = ["txt1", "txt2", "txt3"];
  let test = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
  let ran = ["ran1", "ran2", "ran3"];

  let tst = txt[Math.floor(Math.random() * txt.length)] + "<br><br><br>" + test[Math.floor(Math.random() * test.length)] + "<br><br><br>" + ran[Math.floor(Math.random() * ran.length)];
  document.getElementById("tst").innerHTML = tst;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"> txt<br>
<input type="checkbox"> test<br>
<input type="checkbox"> ran
<br>
<br>

<button onclick="myFunc()">One Character</button>

<p id="tst">
  sum text lol
</p>
```

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/RoseLovesGreene/ps17u8yd/6/

I'd also like to be able to show it in a random order so that each array *doesn't* have it's own line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the values of your checkboxes, you need to give them actual `value`s - and to reference the arrays without a bunch of IF statements, they need to be referencable in something like an object.

This will get random values from each array as it loops the `forEach`, but the final output needs to be shuffled (per your spec). There are many ways of doing this - I grabbed one of the more concise versions, but there are many to choose from here: [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

```js
function shuffle(a, b, c, d) { //array,placeholder,placeholder,placeholder
  c = a.length;
  while (c) b = Math.random() * (--c + 1) | 0, d = a[c], a[c] = a[b], a[b] = d;
  return a
}

function myFunc() {
  let vars = {
    txt: ["txt1", "txt2", "txt3"],
    test: ["test1", "test2", "test3"],
    ran: ["ran1", "ran2", "ran3"]
  }

  // get the checked values into an array
  let flatArr = [];
  document.querySelectorAll('[type=checkbox]:checked').forEach(el => {
      flatArr = [...flatArr, vars[el.value][Math.floor(Math.random() * vars[el.value].length)]]
      });
    document.getElementById("tst").innerHTML = shuffle(flatArr).join(" ");
  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value='txt'> txt<br>
<input type="checkbox" value='test'> test<br>
<input type="checkbox" value='ran'> ran
<br>
<br>

<button onclick="myFunc()">One Character</button>

<p id="tst">
  sum text lol
</p>
```

Comment: this works wonderful, thank you! Is there also a way to show only a certain number of items? like, even if all three are selected, it will show only one from all three lists/arrays? totally get if there isn't :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an if clause to determine whether or not the checkbox is checked. Then if it is checked, use the random number as a key to the array, which you can then append to the result.

```js
 function myFunc() {
     

     let txt = ["txt1", "txt2", "txt3"];
     let test = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
     let ran = ["ran1", "ran2", "ran3"];

     let target = document.getElementById('tst');
     
     let result = "";
     
     let txtKey = [Math.floor(Math.random() * txt.length)]
     let testKey = [Math.floor(Math.random() * test.length)]
     let ranKey = [Math.floor(Math.random() * ran.length)]
     
     
        if (document.getElementById('txt').checked) {
     result = result+txt[txtKey];
     }
     
        if (document.getElementById('test').checked) {
     result = result+test[testKey];
     }
     
        if (document.getElementById('ran').checked) {
     result = result+ran[ranKey];
     }



target.innerHTML = result;
     
     
 }
```

```html
<input id="txt" type="checkbox"> <label for="txt">txt</label><br>
<input id="test" type="checkbox"> <label for="test">test</label><br>
<input id="ran" type="checkbox"> <label for="ran">ran</label>
<br>
<br>

<button onclick="myFunc()">One Character</button>

<p id="tst">
sum text lol
</p>
```

There are a few things that you could do to make this more elegant, but I think the idea works.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Object of arrays
let options = {
  txt : ["txt1", "txt2", "txt3"],
  test : ["test1", "test2", "test3"],
  ran : ["ran1", "ran2", "ran3"]
};

function myFunc() {

  //Get all checkboxes
  let checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
  
  //array for texts from arrays
  let texts = [];
  
  //loop through selected checkboxes
  checkedBoxes.forEach(function(ele) {
  
    // select respective array from object based on checkbox value
    let cOpt = options[ele.value];
    
    // random index for texts array - to randomize array text line
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * checkedBoxes.length);
    
    // to make sure we didn't set a text to that index already
    while( texts[index] !== undefined ) {
      index = Math.floor(Math.random() * checkedBoxes.length);
    }
    
    // set selected array text to a random index in texts array
    texts[index] = cOpt[Math.floor(Math.random() * cOpt.length)];
    
  });

  // text.join() to covert texts array into string
  document.getElementById("tst").innerHTML = texts.join('<br><br>');

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="txt"> txt<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="test"> test<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="ran"> ran<br>

<button onclick="myFunc()">One Character</button>

<p id="tst">
sum text lol
</p>
```

You need to make some adjustments in your approach. i.e set values to checkboxes, create a js obj with all arrays being its property.

Make sure checkboxes values and properties keys are the same.

I have added comments in the code so you can easily understand the purpose of each line.